# Getting Free kms on my Motorbike

Tags: honda, motorcycle, intermittent-problems, speedometer

I've got a Honda CBR 600F (2000 model). It runs perfectly otherwise, but for the last couple of years has had a weird intermittent issue.

About 5 minutes into my journey, the speedo will suddenly drop to 0 and the odometer stops ticking over. This will last for about 5 - 10 minutes, and then it will suddenly start working again.

### More Details

I could almost set a stopwatch for when the speedo stops working, it's so regular, and doesn't seem to matter how far I've gone. BUT it doesn't happen every trip. The length of time before it comes back on does vary. Most of my trips are commuting to work about 15km each way, 2 or 3 days a week, and it will happen about half the time. Sometimes I see the speedo needle "bounce" down to 0 and back again for a short while before it drops off completely.

It never happens more than once in a trip. If I stop for a short time, like filling up petrol, then it won't happen on restart, but if I stop for a bit longer - eg lunch then it will happen again.

While the speedo is at "0", the bike runs like a pig. Under 60km/hr is fine, but trying to accelerate or maintain speed at more than that then it coughs and splutters and jerks like its starving for fuel or missing a cylinder.

While the reduced kms on the speedo is great for resale value I'm sure :D, I'd rather get this fixed. I've already spent a lot of time and $$$ on qualified mechanics that have failed to fix the problem. It's also dangerous when I'm in traffic. My best guess is that something is warming up that causes it, and then stops when at full operating temp, but I don't know of anything that would do it.

Here is the [online manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1974040/Honda-Cbr600f.html).

[image: CBR 600F]

Comment: What work has already been done by mechanics?  Have they replaced parts, for example sensors?

Comment: @HandyHowie no parts replaced. Obviously with the age of the bike, parts can be tricky to find. They told me they swapped out something last time (can't remember what it was), but it didn't make a difference, so they put it back. They also said they have been over the entire wiring and cleaned all the contact points.